# Facebook SDK share dialog not posting user comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the Facebook SDK set up on my web site to share products on Facebook. The Facebook share dialog comes up fine when the share button is clicked, but for some reason the user comment entered into the dialog box doesn't show anywhere in the post. All the open graph stuff that I've specified on the product pages shows up in the post correctly. This used to work but does no longer. I'm not sure if there has been a change in the SDK, but it seems like if the place to put a comment is still in the dialog, then it should still show up in the post. I've looked over SO and have also tried web searches, but can't find anything relating to this issue.

I've got this at the top of each page

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'FB_APPID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=FB_APPID&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And the button looks like this, where get_FB_URL is a function that returns a URL based on user data

```
<div onclick="FB_URL = get_FB_URL(arg1, arg2); FB.ui({method: 'share', href: FB_URL}, function(response){});">
    <a><img src="/images/FB.png" alt="" title="" /> <div class="linkCopy">Facebook</div></a>
</div>
```

On the product pages being shared, I have the following meta tags

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMG URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="PRODUCT TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content=" " />
```

The open graph description is just an empty space because I wanted to override the description that Facebook was getting from the regular description meta tag but didn't actually want anything in that spot in the post.

I tried removing the open graph description to see what happened, but it didn't help.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there something I'm doing or missing that is causing the user comment not to display?

Comment: I feel like this was working two days ago, broken for me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha! It's a bug, they're working on it.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/395435640603415/

Comment: I didn't even know this page existed! Thanks!